# Is it correct to use permutation testing to find the significance of a clustering solution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, clustering, k-means, permutation-test

I am performing exploratory clustering with k-means in a multidimensional (82x18) dataset.

The algorithm that I am using tests several number of clusters and uses several goodness of fit metrics to reach a consensus in order to select the best number of clusters.

What I would like to know is if the final solution (k = 3) that the algorithm found is "real", i.e. if the clusters are really there or I am just observing noise.

I thought to use a permutation approach to this problem:

I have used a ration between the within-cluster and between-clusters distance as an index of how good the solution found with the real data is. I then reasoned that I could approximate the null distribution of this index (i.e. how this index would look like when there is no structure in the data) by shuffling all columns of the dataset at once, thus disrupting any structure in the data. If I repeat this procedure multiple times (e.g. 1000), I can then use standard permutation procedure to derive a p-value.

I am left wondering if this has any sense or if I am applying the permutations testing method well outside its proper use.

Comment: `shuffling all columns of the dataset at once` Do you mean to say you want columns to exchange data randomly independently for every row? That might make sense only if columns are completely comparable features (same measurement units, same variances, etc.). More simple and sane (for me) appraoach is just generate random, non-clustered data to obtain the null. The approach of permutation is risky because ruining a structure does not guarantee moving away from any structure, it might be setting another structure.

Comment: @ttnphns, thanks a lot for your comment. I totally see your point, but then how would you proceed to be sure that the random data you create are not structured in any meaningful wayn? Would it be enough to just draw each column of my dataframe from a normal distribution ?

Comment: Read about gap statistic, one of clustering criterions, it uses random sampling to create a baseline. But honestly, I don't understand why you need such a baseline. Are you testing a hypothesis that you have no clusters (= one cluster) vs 2 or more clusters? If you are comparing cluster solutions with 2 vs 3 vs... clusters you need no "baseline" corresponding to "no cluster structure".

Comment: @ttnphns: the analysis is focused on a set of patients with similar but clinically distinguished pathologies. The point is that we do not know if, within the data at hand, these patients do indeed "cluster" somehow (i.e. these data may not be relevant to separate the patients). Hence the need to compare to some sort of baseline were no clusters exist.